# Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I can't call array in the tableView delegate method cellForRow at indexPath. it gives an error message:

> Cannot assign value of type string to typeString?

```
import UIKit

struct cellData {
    var open = Bool()
    var currentRides = [String]()
    var RequestedRides = [String]()
    var sectionData = [String]()
}

class RideResultViewController: ContentViewController,  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let currentRidesArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
    let RequestedRidesArray = ["A", "B", "C"]

    var tableViewData = [cellData]()

    @IBAction func segmentedValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Expandable cell initailization
        tableViewData = [cellData(open: false, currentRides: currentRidesArray, RequestedRides: RequestedRidesArray, sectionData: ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"])]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text =   tableViewData[indexPath.section].currentRides
        } else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text =    RequestedRidesArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    } else {
        guard let cell =     tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row]
        } else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text =    tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

The code not building. I tied to put it in a square bracket but it still gave same error.

Comment: `tableViewData[indexPath.section].currentRides` => tableViewData[indexPath.section].currentRides[indexPath.row]? `tableViewData[indexPath.section].currentRides` is an Array of String (ie `[String]`), not a `String`

Comment: Could you please specify which array are you trying to call that is giving you the compiler error and if you could point out the line also that is giving you the error it would help in understanding the problem better

Comment: You can not assign array to label title instead of string because both data type is different.

Comment: Thanks @Larme your suggestions worked

Comment: @Nimesh Your suggestions worked thanks

Comment: @nishith Singh.  Your suggestions worked

Answer (score 2):

Its because this is `[String]` an array of String

Change this line to

```
cell.textLabel?.text =   tableViewData[indexPath.section].currentRides
```

This line

```
cell.textLabel?.text =   tableViewData[indexPath.section].currentRides[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: @Diran Could you then accept an answer for this question? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explainary..

> Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'

**It means you are assigning an array of string i.e. [String] to string type which is not allowed.**

When you are setting `cell.textLabel?.text = ...` please make sure that you are assigning `String type` not `[String] type`.